# Navigation Bar overlay its child view

Tags: ios7, scrollview, navigationbar

In iOS 7 I have a navigation controller and add a root view controller to it; but the navigation bar will overlay upper part of this root view controller's view. I know there's a solution that sets `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` but my root view controller contains two sub views: one is scroll view and the other is pagecontrol, and this solution doesn't work out for me. So can anyone help me?